# CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 error

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to play a video from Youtube in my app 
code:

```
videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoView.opaque = NO;
videoView.delegate = self;
videoView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
 videoView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[videoView loadRequest:request];
 [self addSubview:videoView];
videoView=nil;
```

but it shows some errors like:

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 error.
CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0.
 CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0.
 CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0.
CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0.
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
 CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0.
 CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0.
 CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0.
 CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0.
CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0.
```

Comment: Why videoView=nil; after adding videoView on self?

Comment: remove videoView = nil and your problem will be solved.

Comment: i remove videoView nil but it still give same type of error